# the differential of a function $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$: two definitions

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold (on $\mathbb R$). If $p\in M$, we have that
$\Big\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\Big|_p,\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\Big|_p\Big\}$ is a basis for $T_pM$ while $\big\{ dx_1|_p,\ldots ,dx_n|_p  \big\}$ is its dual basis for $T^\ast_pM$. Now if $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ we can recover two definition for the differential of $f$:

1. ${df}_p: T_pM\longrightarrow T_{f(p)}\mathbb R\cong\mathbb R$ is a linear map such that, locally, if the representation of $f$ as function from $\mathbb R^n$ in $\mathbb R$ is $\widehat f$, then the matrix of $df_p$ is $\left(\frac{\partial{\widehat f}(\widehat p)}{\partial x^1},\ldots,\frac{\partial{\widehat f}(\widehat p)}{\partial x^n}\right)$. Clearly $\widehat p$ is the image of $p$ in $\mathbb R^n$ using the charts.
2. $df$ is a differential $1$-form  $df_p:T_pM\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ such that, calculating in local coordinates as below, we have that $df_p=\frac{\partial{\widehat f}(\widehat p)}{\partial x^i} dx_i|_p$ (there is a summation over the index $i$).

Clearly in both cases $df_p$ is an element of $T^\ast_pM$, but in which way are conceptually connected the two definitions? Formally we start from two radically different approaches but we arrive at the same concept!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry what exactly are you asking? How the two definitions are the same?

If you look at the end of each line you end up with two matrices, one of which is represented as an array of numbers and the other as the sum over coordinate dual vectors. Since the coefficients are the same you have the same matrix.

Comment: I don't understand why the differential of a function that represents a local linear approximation can be obtained also in the second way (which I have explained above). The most natural construction is the first; which is the geometrical meaning  behind the second construction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find both definitions equally bad!
The differential of the function $f\in C^\infty (M)$ at $p$  definitely should  **not** depend on the choice of a system of coordinates $(x^1,\cdots,x^n)$ around $p$.
The correct definition is intrinsic, but of course depends on the choice of the definition of "tangent vector".

A) If one decides that a tangent vector $v\in T_pM$ is a derivation $v:C^\infty (M)\to \mathbb R$, then one must define $df_p(v)=v(f)$.
Similarly, if one decides (and it is a better decision) that $v:C^\infty_{M,p} \to \mathbb R$ is a derivation on the germs of smooth functions, then $df_p(v)=v(\text {germ}_pf)$.

B) If one decides that a tangent vector $v\in T_pM$ is given by the equivalence class of a smooth curve $\gamma:I\to M$ with $I$ some real interval around zero and $\gamma(0)=p$ then, if $v$ is the equivalence class of $\gamma$, one defines $df_p(v)=(f\circ \gamma)'(0)$

C) Similarly, every definition of $v\in T_pM$ will lead to a canonical definition of $df_p(v)$.
Coordinates should not be used in the definition of $df_p$, but only for practical calculations.

**Edit: application to original question**
1. Once you have chosen a basis $v_1,\cdots ,v_n$ of a vector space $V$ the matrix of a linear form $\phi:V\to \mathbb R$ is $(\phi(v_1),\cdots, \phi(v_n))=(\cdots,\phi(v_j),\cdots)$
So in your context the $1\times n$  matrix representing $df_p$ is $(\cdots,df_p(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}),\cdots)=(\cdots,\frac{\partial{\widehat f}(\widehat p)}{\partial x^j},\cdots)$

2.If $(v_i^*)$ is the dual basis in $V^*$ to $(v_i)$, we have the formula for an arbitrary linear form $\phi$: $$\phi=\sum \phi(v_i)v_i^*$$ This explains your formula $df_p=\frac{\partial{\widehat f}(\widehat p)}{\partial x^i} dx^i|_p$

The key point in all this is the formula $$  df_p(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})=    \frac{\partial{\widehat f}(\widehat p)}{\partial x^j}$$ following from A) .

Comment: Yes this is clear the tangent vector is an intrinsic object. I'm making effective (local) computations and I marvel at the fact that we obtain the classical expression with partial derivatives.

Comment: Dear Galoisfan, I have written an edit which should clarify how to obtain the classical expression in local coordinates from the intrinsic definition.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what $dx_i$ does; if $V = V^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ (i.e. $V = (V^1,V^2,\dots,V^n)^T$ in local coordinates), then
$$
dx_i(V) = V^i
$$
right?

So, how would you write $dx_i$ as a row vector in these coordinates? It would be
$$
dx_i = (0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)
$$
where the $1$ is in the $i$th position, so 
$$
(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)^T\left(\begin{array}{c}V^1 \\ V^2 \\ \vdots \\ V^n \end{array}\right) = V^i.
$$

From this point of view, it is straightforward to see that

$$
\frac{\partial \widehat f(\widehat p)}{\partial x^i}dx_i
$$
and
$$
\left(\frac{\partial \widehat f(\widehat p)}{\partial x^1},\dots,\frac{\partial \widehat f(\widehat p)}{\partial x^n}\right)
$$
are the same thing.